# Can I power the raspberry pi 0 w off of both ports at once?

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, usb-power

I want to solder a male usb port to my Pi, so that it can be a little dongle computer. However, if I power it with a powerbank, and while it is still being powered, plug it into another power source over the soldered usb connection, will I fry it, since it is being powered twice on the same port? Thanks!

Comment: The +5V & GND pins on both microUSB sockets on a RPiZ are connected. Only the socket furthest from the edge of the board has D+ & D- connected.

Answer (score 1):

As Dougie has commented the ports are joined together.

It is extremely inadvisable to connect the outputs of 2 switch mode power supplies together.

The results are unpredictable.
It is unlikely to damage the Pi and in the best case power will only be drawn from a single supply - the higher voltage causing the other to ramp down.

Normal USB gadgets are designed to be powered by the computer to which they are connected.

I suggest 3 options:

1. Power the Pi from the computer - whether this is feasible depends on the Pi current requirements and/or the computer.
2. Isolate the 5V line so the Pi will not attempt to power the computer.
   This should allow normal USB gadget operation if plugged into a power source.
   I would use a Schottky diode (as I did with the very early Pi to prevent them being back-powered by USB - except the other way round).
   An "ideal" diode (using a MOSFET) would be better - as used in most Pi models, but not Pi0 or Pi4.
3. Ignore the 5V from the computer - by not connecting the 5V line.